# background service call ad and automatic visible background activity on screen

Tags: android, android-service, android-fragmentactivity

Hi I made service for ad will call first time at one minute after every five minute.
this service is run contentiously till kill the app. now i found that if my application activity in background at that time service timer after finish five minute call ad at that time Activity automatically foreground and show me ad in in my application.

now i have to do if my service is running but if my application is in background it didn't want to call ad or activity. if my application activity in foreground at that time ad will show.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: call stopService on your Activity's onStop();

Comment: i have issue with if my application is background then activity not call. my service is stop perfectly on application stop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, override `android.app.Application` class

```
public final class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private static boolean activityVisible;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
    }

    public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;
    }

    public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
    }  
}
```

Then in your manifest file refer to it in application tag

```
  <application
        android:name="*Your Application class*"
        ...
        >
  </application>
```

and in your activity you can do:

```
if(Application.isActivityVisible()){
    //show the ad...
}
```